# add to URL after last /

Tags: javascript, url

using jQuery; to add something to a url after the last **/**

for example add **sale** to:

/gender/category/brand/

so it becomes:

/gender/category/brand/**sale**

However due to the way the URL's are generated and built I can't just always say 'add it to the end of a URL' as there are sometimes ?query strings on the end for example:

/gender/category/brand/**?collection=short&colour=red**

I just can't figure out how I can add **sale** after the final **/** and always before a **?query string** if one exists.

Searching through stackoverflow I've seen some bits about extracting content after the last **/** but not this, is this possible? I really would appreciate help getting this sorted.

**EDIT - The solution**

Thanks too all for your help but I was able to adapt Shree's answer the easiest to get this which did what I needed:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("sale") > -1) {

} else {
    var raw = window.location.href;
    var add = 'sale';
    var rest = raw.substring(0, raw.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    var last = raw.substring(raw.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, raw.length);
    var newUrl = rest + add + last;
    window.location.href = newUrl;
}
```

Comment: Updated tags - this is not a jquery issue, it's vanilla javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `substring` with `lastIndexOf`.

```js
var raw = '/gender/category/brand/?collection=short&colour=red';
var add = 'sale';
var rest = raw.substring(0, raw.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
var last = raw.substring(raw.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, raw.length);
var newUrl = rest + add + last;
console.log(newUrl);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks all, this version from Shree is the one I could adapt best for what I needed so put this as the answer. I've put the updated version of this that worked for me in the original post to help other.

Answer (score 1):

In vanilla javascript

```
var a = "/gender/category/brand/?collection=short&colour=red";
var lastIndexPosition = a.lastIndexOf('/');
a = a.substring(0,lastIndexPosition+1)
    +"sale"
    +a.substring(lastIndexPosition+1 , a.length);
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Thanks, Sorry I may need to add that the **gender** , **category** , **brand** and the strings are just examples and aren't constants, they change depending on how the user navigates through the site, the only constant I can see is the final **/** of url which is why I mentioned it as the target

Comment: Yes, you can replace the above constants to variables by replacing it. I have used as constants just for example.

Answer (score 1):

By using a **reusable function** in Javascript:

You can use `lastIndexOf` and get the **`last '/' index`** position and append your new data there.

> The lastIndexOf() method returns the position of the last occurrence
>   of a specified value in a string.

- **Using this you can send any parameter into function there by it is reusable.**

```js
function insert(main_string, ins_string, pos) {
   return main_string.slice(0, pos) + ins_string + main_string.slice(pos);
}
var url = "/gender/category/brand/?collection=short&colour=red"
url = insert(url, 'sale', url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)
console.log(url)
```

[**Here is a working DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/pPEpyqsz5g9eBeD9SerZ?p=preview)

Comment: @Chobbit,I created a reusable function where you can use any `url` and send any `string` to replace

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, use `.split("?")` to separate at the `?` then combine them back, eg:

```js
// Example with querystring
var url = '/gender/category/brand/?collection=short&colour=red'
var parts = url.split("?");
var newurl = parts[0] + "sale" + "?" + (parts[1]||"")
console.log(newurl)

// Test without querystring
var url = '/gender/category/brand/'
var parts = url.split("?");
var newurl = parts[0] + "sale" + (parts[1]||"")
console.log(newurl)
```

The `(parts[1]||"")` handles the case where there isn't a querystring.